# How to use Firestore and Room together in MVVM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-room, android-mvvm

My app currently uses Room for all its storage needs. It has a fairly complex database hierarchy, where there are two parent tables A and B (both <20 rows each) which then have children tables A1,A2,A3 and B1,B2. These sub-tables are quite data heavy with a few thousand rows each which are updated daily.

I recently learned about Firebase and specifically, authentification and cloud Firestore. I would like to leverage this for my app, so that when a user logs on from another device, they can be using the same synced data across devices.

Given my data structure mentioned in first paragraph, the way I am thinking of approaching it is having Tables A and B on Firestore. This will pull the core metadata needed and have small number of rows. I will then use this data to update the sub tables A1-A3 and B1-B2 which will be performed locally using Room.

I am having some trouble thinking about how I would integrate these two approaches together. For example, how to aggregate the parent and child table data in the domain layer. I previously used Room relational tables for this but that does not seem like an option now some of my tables are coming Firestore. Does anyone have any ideas/materials on how to use Firestore and Room in this way?

Comment: If you mix [this](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d), here is the [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle) with [this](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-room-using-kotlin-flow-in-jetpack-compose-7a720dec35f5), here is the [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/RoomJetpackCompose), then you'll achieve what you want.

Comment: Along with recommendations from Alex in the comment above you may also check and see if this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/android-mvvm-firestore-37c3a8d65404) helps you with the query. Alongside that article I also found a similar [Stack Overflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74487629/20239914).